# Combining data from multiple workbooks into a master

Tags: vba, excel

I have been searching forums and just can't work out the issue with my code. I am very new to macros and I'm sure it's something simple, like some variable not being defined, but I can't figure it out.
I am trying to load data from multiple workbooks into a master and really need help please!

```
Dir for source files: C:\Test Dir\
Dir for Master: C:\Test Dir\Master\
```

Source filenames differ, but all end in "*FORMATTED.xlsx."

Master filename: `"Payroll Master.xlsx"`

Source worksheet name = "Loaded Data"

Master worksheet name = "Summary"

All SOURCE data is in A2:J106.

The top row in the source and Master files are column headers and are identical.
 I am loading all data into the Master file "Summary" worksheet.

My latest error is: `"Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed."` on the `"Sheets("Loaded Data").Range("A2:J106").Select"` line

This is my current code:

```
Sub combine_data()
'
Dim MyPath As String
Dim SumPath As String
Dim MyName As String
Dim SumName As String
'Dim MyTemplate As Workbook
'Dim SumTemplate As Workbook
MyPath = "C:\Test Dir\"
SumPath = "C:\Test Dir\Master\"
MyTemplate = "*.xlsx"  'Set the template.
SumTemplate = "Payroll MASTER.xlsx"
MyName = Dir(MyPath & MyTemplate)    'Retrieve the first file
SumName = Dir(SumPath & SumTemplate)

Do While MyName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open MyPath & MyName
Sheets("Loaded Data").Range("A2:J106").Select
Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Open SumPath & SumName
Sheets("Summary").Select
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Workbooks(MyName).Close SaveChanges:=False        'close
Workbooks(SumName).Close SaveChanges:=True
MyName = Dir                    'Get next file
Loop
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot select a range on a non-active worksheet. By the way, you don't have to select anything first, just apply the method right away.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand what that means. Doesn't the Workbooks.Open MyPath & MyName line activate the workbooks? (As well as the Open SumPath & SumName line.)

Comment: Yes, it does. But is the right worksheet active after opening the workbook?

Comment: may be iteresting: [Excel macro - Avoiding using Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: Kapol: I don't know what worksheet is active, since I get an error and see no results. Thank you, but I'm just very new to this and clueless.

Comment: simco: thank you and I will read this. I just need to try to get this working ASAP and I am not a programmer and am having a hard time. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce bugs, you should state `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. You will then be told when using variables that are not declared and you reduce the risk of misspelling the names of variables.

You should put the `SumName = Dir(SumPath & SumTemplate)` just before the loop, as the `Dir` at the end of your `Do While ... Loop` will refer to the LAST `Dir` that had parameters. When getting past the error with the Select that you describe, you have ran into this problem.

Inside your loop, you should refer to each workbook/worksheet individually, to clarify what you are doing (helping yourself for the future).

You are opening and closing the MASTER file for every source-file. You could open it before the Loop and close it after. This will make your script faster.

Here is the code modified with the above comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub combine_data()
'
Dim MyPath As String
Dim SumPath As String
Dim MyName As String
Dim SumName As String
Dim MyTemplate As String
Dim SumTemplate As String
Dim myWS As Worksheet
Dim sumWS As Worksheet

'Define folders and filenames
MyPath = "C:\Test Dir\"
SumPath = "C:\Test Dir\Master\"
MyTemplate = "*.xlsx"  'Set the template.
SumTemplate = "Payroll MASTER.xlsx"

'Open the template file and get the Worksheet to put the data into
SumName = Dir(SumPath & SumTemplate)
Workbooks.Open SumPath & SumName
Set sumWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

'Open each source file, copying the data from each into the template file
MyName = Dir(MyPath & MyTemplate)    'Retrieve the first file
Do While MyName <> ""
    'Open the source file and get the worksheet with the data we want.
    Workbooks.Open MyPath & MyName
    Set myWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Loaded Data")
    'Copy the data from the source and paste at the end of Summary sheet
    myWS.Range("A2:J106").Copy
    sumWS.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    'Close the current sourcefile and get the next
    Workbooks(MyName).Close SaveChanges:=False        'close
    MyName = Dir                    'Get next file
Loop
'Now all sourcefiles are copied into the Template file. Close and save it
Workbooks(SumName).Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: One additional question, as the script runs, it stops for each source workbook and tells me "there is a large amount of data on the clipboard, would you like to save it?" Do you know how to get rid of that? Thanks again!

Comment: You just copy something else to the clipboard before closing, which is small, like cell A1.